# Proof of a property of the uniformly continuous semigroups.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-calculus, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:=\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ an uniformly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators on $X$.

So, we know that

> (i) $T(t)$ is linear and bounded for all $t\geq 0$;
>   (ii) $T(0)=I$;
>   (iii) $T(t + s)= T(t)T(s)$ for every $t,s\geq 0$;
>   (iv) $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|T(t)-I\|=0.$

I need help to prove that the following equality holds.

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\left\|\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h}T(s)ds-T(t)\right\|=0.$$

Thanks.

Comment: Write $s = t+\eta$ in the integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer It is just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, we have by the semigroup property (iii)

$$\begin{align*} \frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} T(s) \, ds - T_t &=\frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} (T(s)-T(t)) \, ds \\ &=\frac{1}{h} \int_0^h T_t(T(s)-I) \, ds. \end{align*}$$

Since $T(t)$ is a bounded operator, this implies

$$\begin{align*} \left\| \frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} T(s) \,ds - T(t) \right\| &\leq \frac{1}{h} \int_0^h \|T(t)\| \cdot \|T(s)-I\| \, ds \\ &\leq \|T(t)\| \cdot \sup_{s \leq h} \|T(s)-I\|.\end{align*}$$

As $\lim_{h \downarrow 0+} \|T(h)-I\|=0$, this finishes the proof.

Comment: You are right. We have $\|\cdot\|$ instead of $\|\cdot\|_X$. I corrected it.

Comment: @Pedro Well, more importantly the factor $\frac{1}{h}$ in front of the integral is missing.

Comment: Sorry! I think that it's all right now. Thanks for the correction.