# What is an integral of operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am reading the book *Semigroups of Linear Operatos and Applications to Partial Differential Equations* which studies a uniformly continuous semigroup, this is a family $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of bounded operators $T :X \to X$ on a Banachspace $X$ with

- $T(0)=Id$
- $T_{s+t}=T_s T_t$
- $ \lim_{t \to 0^+} || T_t - I || = 0$

They define the infinitesimal generator as
$$ Ax :=\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{T_tx -x}{t} $$
for $x \in \mathcal{D}(A) := \{  x \in X \mid \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{T_tx -x}{t} \text{ exists} \}.$

Theorem 1.2 states

> A linear operator A is the infinitesimal generator of a uniformly continuous  semigroup if and only if A is a bounded linear operator

I am having difficulties to understand one direction of the proof, namely that for a uniformly continuous semigroup you find a bounded linear operator. The start of the proof goes like this:

> Let $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a uniformly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators on $X$. Fix $\rho >0 $ small enough, such that $$||I - \rho^{-1} \int_0^{\rho}T(s) \, ds|| < 1$$

But how is the integral of operators defined and why can you assure such a $\rho> 0$?

Comment: Because $s\mapsto T(s)$ is continuous, a Riemann integral works just fine, and $\|\int_{0}^{\rho}T(s)ds\| \le \int_{0}^{\rho}\|T(s)\|ds$, where the integral on the right is an ordinary Riemann integral of a continuous real function. So $I-\rho^{-1}\int_{0}^{\rho}T(s)ds=\rho^{-1}\int_{0}^{\rho}(I-T(s))ds$ is easily estimated.

Comment: @TrialAndError could you give a reference? I have no idea how to extend the Riemann integral to a function that takes values in the operator space $L(X)$.

Comment: Form Riemann sums of a vector-valued function $f$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$. $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is just another vector space. Use uniform continuity to show that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $\|S(f,\mathcal{P})-S(f,\mathcal{Q})\| < \epsilon$ whenever $\|\mathcal{P}\|,\|\mathcal{Q}\| < \delta$. Choose $\|\mathcal{P}_{n}\| < 1/n$ and get a Cauchy sequence of Riemann sums; prove that the limit is unique and $\|S(f,\mathcal{P})-L\| \rightarrow 0$ as $\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0$. Basically, copy existence result for ordinary Riemann integrals. I don't have a ref.

Answer (score 1):

**How is the integral of operators defined?**

See Appendix E.5 in [Evans book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=evans+partial+differential+equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=OYGJVaLpI8X-gwS_i4NA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false), where he extends

> the notions of measurability, integrability, etc. to mappings $\mathbf{f} : [0, T]\to X $ where $T > 0$ and $X$ is a real Banach space, with norm $\|\;\|$.

See Appendix C in [Engel's book](https://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf) where he gives

> a brief introduction to the so-called Bochner integration of vector-valued functions.

See Chapter 1 in [Vrabie's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=T3lC9r51FEYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=vrabie+semigroups&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=nYOJVaPANcOogwT8kIzgDg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=vrabie%20semigroups&f=false) where he defines and studies

> the class of vector-valued measurable functions as well as the integral of such functions.

**Why can you assure such a $\rho>0$?**

Because $\displaystyle \lim_{\rho\to0^+}\left\|\frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^\rho T(s)\ ds-I\right\|=0$. See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638136/proof-of-a-property-of-the-uniformly-continuous-semigroups).